# Fatal error: Call to undefined function drupal_get_path()

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

After updating our server to PHP 5.4 and a Drupal site to Drupal 6.37 I keep getting this error message and I am not able to get past it

> **Fatal error: Call to undefined function drupal_get_path() in /home/mysite/public_html/includes/module.inc on line 285**

this is the related function call

```
function module_load_include($type, $module, $name = NULL) {
if (empty($name)) {
$name = $module;
}

$file = './'. drupal_get_path('module', $module) ."/$name.$type";

if (is_file($file)) {
require_once $file;
}
else {
return FALSE;
}
}
```

Even when I try to run update.php I still get the same error

I am new to Drupal so any help will be greatly appreciated

Please let me know what additional info you may need since it is my first post here and as I said I don't know much about Drupal

Comment: how/where is this file being loaded?

Comment: Check this link https://www.drupal.org/node/2248149 , this issue caused by php 5.4 version

Comment: as far as i am aware module.inc is a drupal core file, could you be more specific ?

Comment: Did you update drupal core ? Check version of module in module.info

Comment: I did update drupal core and the first time it went through but afterwards it started showing this error message. I tried deleting and updating again but the error persists. I think i will try to delete one by one the modules to see if there is a conflict there.

Comment: Did you have drush ? use Drush to update DB ! verify .info file of your module if the new version is compatible with drupal core update ! It seems to be a version mismatch between core and modules

Comment: I will try your suggestion and will report the results here. Thanks for the help so far

Comment: It turned out to be a conflict with Custom Breadcrumbs module after updating it. Thanks again for all your help

Comment: @TheodoreGavriilidis Amazing Shout. that would have taken me all night to find.... thanks!